# make controller return HTML or JSON depending on request type

Tags: ajax, grails, controller, action

I want to know if there is a way in Grails to return HTML or JSON depending if I make a GET to an action or if I just call an action through Ajax.

For example, if I make an Ajax call to "controller/action", is there a way to return JSON and if I go to the same "controller/action" trough a link, make it render an HTML page? or i have to define two diferent actions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically all AJAX requests have [`X-Requested-With`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) header set. You can check if this header is set and render desired format of response:

```
if (request.getHeader('X-Requested-With')) {
    // render response as JSON
} else {
    // render HTML page
}
```

Or (as Martin Hauner pointed out in comments) use `request.xhr` property which do basically the same and returns `true` if current request is an AJAX:

```
if (request.xhr) {
    // render response as JSON
} else {
    // render HTML page
}
```

`request` is an object representing current request. [Read more about it in Grails documentation.](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Servlet%20API/request.html)

Comment: we can use request.xhr to check the ajax request: http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Servlet%20API/request.html

Comment: @MartinHauner: Thanks for pointing out! I've updated my answer. Actually it's good to know about `xhr` property because until now I was always checking headers :)

Comment: +1 to Pawel & Martin and +1 to Marcos for the Ques, this works..thanks I was trying something similar.

Comment: Thank you guys! I cannot give any points yet but it's good to know that there are two ways to do that!

Comment: @Marcos: I'm glad it helped. You can probably accept my answer if it was helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

[withFormat](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/ref/Controllers/withFormat.html) builder is here to help:

```
class BookController {

  def list() {
    def books = Book.list()

    withFormat {
        html bookList:books
        js { render books as JSON }
        xml { render books as XML }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes its Possible,

if you difine in your controller

```
if(isset($_post) || isset(#_get)){
//if something is posted then this should execute
}
else
{
//this portion should execute..
}
```

its a rough code, might be some mistakes but you get the idea..

Your Ajax Call will post data depend on the type
`type:"POST"` or `type:"GET"` in your Ajax.. 
which you can get in controller. if controller sees that there is something posting then controller will do action accordingly.
or if nothing is posted which you are looking for let controller send the HTML code.

Comment: Ok, is there a way to do it in grails? I mean, I've seen that there's a respond method but I don't get it at all. (Sorry for my bad english)