# Returning HTML or JSON based on header type Nodejs

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

My nodeJS Api needs to return HTML or Json based on the header. If the header is:

```
Accept = application/json
```

The Api needs to return Json else my Api needs to return a HTML file.

this is the code I use on my routes:

```
var app = express();
app.use('/auth', require('./routes/Authenticate'));
```

In the Authenticate file I catch /login, and do the login stuff. if it succeeds I redirect to /users. In the /users I check for the Accept with an if statement:

```
router.get('/users', function(req,res){
    if(req.get('Accept') === 'application/json'){
       res.json({ success: true, user: req.user });
    } else {
        res.render("account/profile") //redirect to the file
    }
});
```

This works(from this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25497313/make-controller-return-html-or-json-depending-on-request-type)) but is there a better way? Because there are like 20 endpoints and the application is growing and this will be a mess for every endpoint.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. You are writing a handler for a GET request. There shouldn't be a `Content-Type` header on the request because there is no request body for it to describe the type of. Are you confusing the `Content-Type` header with the `Accept` header?

Comment: @Quentin your right, edited it thank you!

Comment: You should use a proper parser for the Accept header. What if the browser sends: `Accept: application/json;q=1, application/xml;q=0.9, */*; 0.8`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38412980/how-to-determine-the-right-accept-content-type-with-expressjs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can split these actions into 2 functions. One to verify the content type and an other to doing your actions.

```
router.get('/users', checkIfJson, action);

function checkIfJson(req, res, next) {
    if(!(req.get('Content-Type') === 'application/json')) {
        res.render("account/profile");
        return;
    }
    next();
}

function action(req, res) {
    res.json({ success: true, user: req.user });
    return;
}
```

If you write your code like that you can reuse your checkIfJson into other routes.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I've done—seems pretty straightforward.

```
router.get("/foo", HTML_ACCEPTED, (req, res) => res.send("<html><h1>baz</h1><p>qux</p></html>"))
router.get("/foo", JSON_ACCEPTED, (req, res) => res.json({foo: "bar"}))
```

Here's how those middlewares work.

```
function HTML_ACCEPTED (req, res, next) { return req.accepts("html") ? next() : next("route") }
function JSON_ACCEPTED (req, res, next) { return req.accepts("json") ? next() : next("route") }
```

Personally I think this is quite readable (and therefore maintainable).

```
$ curl localhost:5000/foo --header "Accept: text/html"
<html><h1>baz</h1><p>qux</p></html>

$ curl localhost:5000/foo --header "Accept: application/json"
{"foo":"bar"}
```

Notes:

- I recommend putting the `HTML` routes before the `JSON` routes because some browsers will accept HTML *or* JSON, so they'll get whichever route is listed first. I'd expect API users to be capable of understanding and setting the Accept header, but I wouldn't expect that of browser users, so browsers get preference.
- The last paragraph in [ExpressJS Guide](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.application) talks about `next('route')`. In short, `next()` skips to the next middleware *in the same route* while `next('route')` bails out of this route and tries the next one.
- Here's the reference on [req.accepts](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.accepts).

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap router.get function with a custom function

```
router.wrappedGet = function (path, callback) {
    router.get(path, function (req, res) {
        if (req.get('Content-Type') === 'application/json') {
            res.render = res.json;
        }
        callback(req, res);
    })
};
```